# Question about the definition of the definite integral (What if I change n - 1 to ∞?)

Tags: calculus

I just happen to wonder about the definition of the definite integral.

According to my math book, the definition of the definite integral is:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+k\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\right)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

But what if I change $n-1$ to $\infty$?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f\left(a+k\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\right)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=?$$

I think there is no problem because due to $\lim$, $n-1$ eventually goes to $\infty$ after all.

p.s. I'm a totally math newbie. So it would be appreciated if you explain your answer in an easy way, if possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: This expression does not make sense.  Given that $f$ is bounded away from $0$ in the relevant interval, your sum would be infinite for any fixed $n$.  Consider the case where $f$ is the constant $1$, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: not all $\infty$'s are the same.

The notation of $\infty$ on top of $\Sigma$ is defined to be:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\cdots):= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^m (\cdots)$$

So if you write $\sum^\infty$, it means there are two independent and different infinities: $m$ and $n$. But in the original equation there was no $m$, and adding $m$ might cause some problems such as making the sum diverge.